# Trying to push data on firebase db using react-native app but it does not do anything

Tags: react-native

```
import React from "react";
    import {
      Modal,
      ScrollView,
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      Button,
      TouchableOpacity,
      TextInput,
      Text,
      View
    } from "react-native";
    import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
    import ModalSelector from "react-native-modal-selector";
    import {
      AppStyles,
      AppIcon,
      ModalHeaderStyle,
      ModalSelectorStyle,
      HeaderButtonStyle
    } from "../AppStyles";
    import TextButton from "react-native-button";
    import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
    import { Configuration } from "../Configuration";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
    import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
    import FilterViewModal from "../components/FilterViewModal";
    import SelectLocationModal from "../components/SelectLocationModal";
    import ActionSheet from "react-native-actionsheet";
    import Geocoder from "react-native-geocoding";

    class PostModal extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        Geocoder.init("AIzaSyCDeWXVrJxUCRQlpcWK2JJQSB-kFVjCqlM");

        const categories = this.props.categories;
        let category = {};

        if (categories.length > 0) category = categories[0];

        this.state = {
          categories: categories,
          category: category,
          title: "",
          description: "",
          location: {
            latitude: Configuration.map.origin.latitude,
            longitude: Configuration.map.origin.longitude
          },
          localPhotos: [],
          photoUrls: [],
          price: "$1000",
          textInputValue: "",
          filter: {},
          filterValue: "Select...",
          address: "Checking...",
          filterModalVisible: false,
          locationModalVisible: false
        };

        this.setFilterString(this.state.filter);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            this.setState({ location: position.coords });
            this.onChangeLocation(position.coords);
          },
          error => alert(error.message),
          { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 1000 }
        );
      }

      selectLocation = () => {
        this.setState({ locationModalVisible: true });
      };

      onChangeLocation = location => {
        Geocoder.from(location.latitude, location.longitude)
          .then(json => {
            var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[0];
            this.setState({ address: addressComponent });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({ address: "Unknown" });
          });
      };

      setFilterString = filter => {
        let filterValue = "";
        Object.keys(filter).forEach(function(key) {
          if (filter[key] != "Any" && filter[key] != "All") {
            filterValue += " " + filter[key];
          }
        });

        if (filterValue == "") {
          if (Object.keys(filter).length > 0) {
            filterValue = "Any";
          } else {
            filterValue = "Select...";
          }
        }

        this.setState({ filterValue: filterValue });
      };

      onSelectLocationDone = location => {
        this.setState({ location: location });
        this.setState({ locationModalVisible: false });
        this.onChangeLocation(location);
      };

      onSelectLocationCancel = () => {
        this.setState({ locationModalVisible: false });
      };

      selectFilter = () => {
        this.setState({ filterModalVisible: true });
      };

      onSelectFilterCancel = () => {
        this.setState({ filterModalVisible: false });
      };

      onSelectFilterDone = filter => {
        this.setState({ filter: filter });
        this.setState({ filterModalVisible: false });
        this.setFilterString(filter);
      };

      onPressAddPhotoBtn = () => {
        // More info on all the options is below in the API Reference... just some common use cases shown here
        const options = {
          title: "Select a photo",
          storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: "images"
          }
        };

        /**
         * The first arg is the options object for customization (it can also be null or omitted for default options),
         * The second arg is the callback which sends object: response (more info in the API Reference)
         */
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log("User cancelled image picker");
          } else if (response.error) {
            console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
          } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
          } else {
            this.setState({
              localPhotos: [...this.state.localPhotos, response.uri]
            });
          }
        });
      };

      onCancel = () => {
        this.props.onCancel();
      };

      onPost = () => {
        const navigation = this.props.navigation;
        const onCancel = this.onCancel;

        if (!this.state.title) {
          alert("Title was not provided.");
          return;
        }
        if (!this.state.description) {
          alert("Description was not set.");
          return;
        }
        if (!this.state.price) {
          alert("Price is empty");
          return;
        }
        if (this.state.localPhotos.length == 0) {
          alert("Please pick photos");
          return;
        }

        if (Object.keys(this.state.filter).length == 0) {
          alert("Please set filters");
          return;
        }

        let photoUrls = [];

        uploadPromiseArray = [];
        this.state.localPhotos.forEach(uri => {
          uploadPromiseArray.push(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              let filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
              const uploadUri =
                Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;
              firebase
                .storage()
                .ref(filename)
                .putFile(uploadUri)
                .then(function(snapshot) {
                  photoUrls.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
                  resolve();
                });
            })
          );
        });

        Promise.all(uploadPromiseArray)
          .then(values => {
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("real_estate_listings")
              .add({
                user_id: this.props.user.id,
                category_id: this.state.category.id,
                description: this.state.description,
                latitude: this.state.location.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.location.longitude,
                mapping: this.state.filter,
                name: this.state.title,

                price: this.state.price,
                //coordinate: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(
                  //this.state.location.latitude,
                 // this.state.location.longitude
               // ),
                post_time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                //TODO:
                place: "New Satellite Town, Sargodha",
                cover_photo: photoUrls[0],
                list_of_photos: photoUrls
              })
              .then(function(docRef) {
                onCancel();
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                alert(error);
              });
          })
          .catch(reason => {
            console.log(reason);
          });
      };

      showActionSheet = index => {
        this.setState({
          selectedPhotoIndex: index
        });
        this.ActionSheet.show();
      };

      onActionDone = index => {
        if (index == 0) {
          var array = [...this.state.localPhotos];
          array.splice(this.state.selectedPhotoIndex, 1);
          this.setState({ localPhotos: array });
        }
      };

      render() {
        categoryData = this.state.categories.map((category, index) => ({
          key: category.id,
          label: category.name
        }));
        categoryData.unshift({ key: "section", label: "Category", section: true });

        photos = this.state.localPhotos.map((photo, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.showActionSheet(index);
            }}
          >
            <FastImage style={styles.photo} source={{ uri: photo }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ));
        return (
          <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={false}
            onRequestClose={this.onCancel}
          >
            <View style={ModalHeaderStyle.bar}>
              <Text style={ModalHeaderStyle.title}>Add Listing</Text>
              <TextButton
                style={[ModalHeaderStyle.rightButton, styles.rightButton]}
                onPress={this.onCancel}
              >
                Cancel
              </TextButton>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={styles.body}>
              <View style={styles.section}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Title</Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  value={this.state.title}
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ title: text })}
                  placeholder="Start typing"
                  placeholderTextColor={AppStyles.color.grey}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.divider} />
              <View style={styles.section}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Description</Text>
                <TextInput
                  multiline={true}
                  numberOfLines={2}
                  style={styles.input}
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ description: text })}
                  value={this.state.description}
                  placeholder="Start typing"
                  placeholderTextColor={AppStyles.color.grey}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.divider} />
              <View style={styles.section}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>Price</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.priceInput}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={this.state.price}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ price: text })}
                    placeholderTextColor={AppStyles.color.grey}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  />
                </View>
                <ModalSelector
                  touchableActiveOpacity={0.9}
                  data={categoryData}
                  sectionTextStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.sectionTextStyle}
                  optionTextStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.optionTextStyle}
                  optionContainerStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.optionContainerStyle}
                  cancelContainerStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.cancelContainerStyle}
                  cancelTextStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.cancelTextStyle}
                  selectedItemTextStyle={ModalSelectorStyle.selectedItemTextStyle}
                  backdropPressToClose={true}
                  cancelText={"Cancel"}
                  initValue={this.state.category.name}
                  onChange={option => {
                    this.setState({
                      category: { id: option.key, name: option.label }
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Category</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.value}>{this.state.category.name}</Text>
                  </View>
                </ModalSelector>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectFilter}>
                  <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Filters</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.value}>{this.state.filterValue}</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectLocation}>
                  <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Location</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.value}>{this.state.address}</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.addPhotoTitle}>Add Photos</Text>
                <ScrollView style={styles.photoList} horizontal={true}>
                  {photos}
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressAddPhotoBtn.bind(this)}>
                    <View style={[styles.addButton, styles.photo]}>
                      <Icon name="camera" size={30} color="white" />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
              {this.state.filterModalVisible && (
                <FilterViewModal
                  value={this.state.filter}
                  onCancel={this.onSelectFilterCancel}
                  onDone={this.onSelectFilterDone}
                />
              )}
              {this.state.locationModalVisible && (
                <SelectLocationModal
                  location={this.state.location}
                  onCancel={this.onSelectLocationCancel}
                  onDone={this.onSelectLocationDone}
                />
              )}
            </ScrollView>
            <TextButton
              containerStyle={styles.addButtonContainer}
              onPress={this.onPost}
              style={styles.addButtonText}
            >
              Post Listing
            </TextButton>
            <ActionSheet
              ref={o => (this.ActionSheet = o)}
              title={"Confirm to delete?"}
              options={["Confirm", "Cancel"]}
              cancelButtonIndex={1}
              destructiveButtonIndex={0}
              onPress={index => {
                this.onActionDone(index);
              }}
            />
          </Modal>
        );
      }
    }
    const actionSheetStyles = {
      titleBox: {
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      },
      titleText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: "#000fff"
      }
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      body: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: AppStyles.color.white
      },
      divider: {
        backgroundColor: AppStyles.color.background,
        height: 10
      },
      container: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        height: 65,
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: AppStyles.color.grey
      },
      rightButton: {
        marginRight: 10
      },
      sectionTitle: {
        textAlign: "left",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: AppStyles.color.title,
        fontSize: 19,
        padding: 10,
        paddingTop: 15,
        paddingBottom: 7,
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.bold,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderBottomColor: AppStyles.color.grey
      },
      input: {
        width: "100%",
        fontSize: 19,
        padding: 10,
        textAlignVertical: "top",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.main,
        color: AppStyles.color.text
      },
      priceInput: {
        flex: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: AppStyles.color.grey,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        height: 40,
        textAlign: "right",
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.main,
        color: AppStyles.color.text
      },
      title: {
        flex: 2,
        textAlign: "left",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: AppStyles.color.title,
        fontSize: 19,
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.bold,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      },
      value: {
        textAlign: "right",
        color: AppStyles.color.description,
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.main
      },
      section: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        marginBottom: 10
      },
      row: {
        height: 50,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10
      },
      addPhotoTitle: {
        color: AppStyles.color.title,
        fontSize: 19,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.bold,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      },
      photoList: {
        height: 70,
        marginTop: 20,
        marginRight: 10
      },
      photo: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 10
      },

      addButton: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: AppStyles.color.tint
      },
      photoIcon: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      },
      addButtonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: AppStyles.color.tint,
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 15,
        margin: 10,
        marginTop: 20
      },
      addButtonText: {
        color: AppStyles.color.white,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontFamily: AppStyles.fontName.bold,
        fontSize: 15
      }
    });

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      user: state.auth.user
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostModal);
```

I expect a return like "data successfully inserted or something like that" but It actually do nothing.

Comment: any error message throwing up?

Comment: This is probably too much code for an [mcve]. Are you able to cut it down, to help isolate where the problem is?